# Blender Video Editor over 2.83 doesn't show transparent movie background anymore

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

I made an overlay using blender and wanted to export it with a transparent background. To that end I followed the usual guides (select transparent, ffmpeg Quicktime - Qt encoding).

When I import the overlay into After Effects, it complains that

> The item has an unlabeled alpha channel.

If I select "Premultiplied - Matted with Color #000000" to interpret the footage then everything works just fine in AE, that is the overlay works immediately as expected.

However, in Blender's own video editor, the overlay just doesn't work. It shows as having a black background! I've tried Alpha Over and just about everything else in the dropdown.
It works with image sequences though.

Tried this in 3.01 and 2.93 without luck.

EDIT: Also tried it in a fresh project with just the default cube. Same issue there.

EDIT 2: **If I use blender 2.83 it works fine.**
The transparent bg `.mov`s exported from 2.93/3.01 work as expected in 2.83 video editor.

Is this a bug or was the way transparent background movie clips are handled changed intentionally?

Comment: pls provide a simple blend file with your problem

Comment: Well, movie files with transparency are quite tricky. It seems the _Blender Video Sequence Editor_ doesn't support premultiplied videos with alpha channel. If you instead import the movie into the _Compositor_ it works as expected. Generally I would always suggest for best quality etc. to render frames in a format which is best to work with in the software you intend to use for further adjustments/composition.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I was just editing. I'll see if I can do what I want in the compositor in a current version, thanks for the hint. Version hopping is apparently also an option.

Comment: For example if you're going to use it in Blender _VSE_, then if you render the frames as images in _OpenEXR_ format, an imported sequence will by default be set to _Color Space_ > _Linear_ and _Alpha_ > _Premultiplied_. These settings don't even exist for an imported movie in the _VSE_. The difference in the _Compositor_ is, it uses color space  and alpha correctly when you import the Quicktime movie. Maybe there is some magic setting somewhere in the _VSE_, but I haven't found it yet. It seems like the "Add Movie Clip" option is made for "standard" videos that don't accept transparency.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Yes, image sequences worked like a charm, in the newer versions, too.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the *Proxy* tab?

Here is what worked for me:

1. Click on the video strip that needs to be on top.
2. On the right side on the *Strip* tab
3. Under *Composition* select *Alpha Over*.
4. Then click on the tab called *Proxy*, click on that and unblock
   100%.
5. Then go back to the *Strip* tab and right next to that word *Strip*
   is a little check mark. Uncheck it and check it again and it works in my case.